# Navigation Drawer with always visible tab image

Tags: android, menu, drawerlayout

[image]
[image]

I have to implement this sliding menu on the left. `DrawerLayout` works good, the only problem is with this always visible tab image:

[image]

Normally all Drawer is hidden, but I need this small rectangle to stick out. How can I do it? Maybe I should use `SlidingPaneLayout` instead?

[Here](http://www.speedyshare.com/j2nPE/download/Test.zip) you have a tiny, ready-to-run Eclipse Android project with the implementation of `DrawerLayout` (50 lines of Java + 35 lines of XML). It's truncated version of sample from [documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html).

Comment: can you please share the code ? i also want to implement this :)

Comment: @Tarsem You are clicking the wrong link. The link for my zip is on the top of the page, it's `Download: Test.zip`. You're downloading some manager advertised by them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried different approaches, but finally used [this](https://github.com/kedzie/DraggableDrawers) generalization of [`SlidingDrawer`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SlidingDrawer.html), which allows to slide from left to right (and in other directions too). Code is well-written and it works like a charm. Tab image is an `ImageView` with `@+id/handle`, menu is a `LinearLayout` with `@+id/content`.

Comment: What if I want to do it by myself? what should I do?